Why i get the error 'Starting in Kotlin 2.0, the Compose Compiler Gradle plugin is required when compose is enabled' even after adding the plugin?
libs.versions.toml file:
[versions]
kotlin = "2.0.10"

[plugins]
org-jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }


compose-compiler = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", version.ref = "kotlin" }

Here are the build.gradle.kts files:
Project level:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.7.2" apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler) apply false
}

module level:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "2.1.0"
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
}

composeCompiler {
    reportsDestination = layout.buildDirectory.dir("compose_compiler")
    stabilityConfigurationFile = rootProject.layout.projectDirectory.file("stability_config.conf")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.testroom"
    compileSdk = 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.testroom"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 35
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
//    composeOptions {
//        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.15"
//    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.15.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.8.7")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.3")

    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.12.01"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.8.7")

    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.6.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:25.1.1")

    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.8.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.8.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:2.8.4")

    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.7.5")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.1.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.7.3")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.12.01"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")

    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}

It works exactly the same without the composeCompiler block, which was to add the plugin by using gradle plugin.
I tried to solve it using version catalog, where i added the plugins to libs.versions.toml file (which i created manually) and used alias in the project and module level build files.
I also removed the composeOptions block, which used to set the compose version, no more needed for kotlin versions 2.0.0+ as we are using the compose compiler.

This question is similar to: Cannot Use Kotlin 2.0 Features After Upgrade. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I cannot reproduce the issue. I just created a new project and added the code from your question, removed the plugin com.google.gms.google-services (for simplicity's sake) and added an empty stability_config.conf. The project then successfully syncs, builds and runs on the emulator, without any issues. Please also try this yourself and then compare this new (working) project with your failing project. If you still have questions please [edit] and provide a [mre] that we can use to actually reproduce the issue.
